# Why would one ever throw a non-symbol?

Tags: ruby

Ruby's `throw` statement accepts any `Object`, which means any of these below are legal.

```
throw BasicObject
throw 123456.78
throw "wow"
throw :doge
```

In my understanding, however, there are 2 reasons why I would choose to throw a `Symbol`.

1. One must `catch` the exact same `Object` that was thrown. This means that doing `catch "wow"` would result in an `UncaughtThrowError`. This is not a problem when using `Symbol`s.
2. The `Object` that was thrown cannot be referenced after a `catch`. To specify a return value, one would input it as the 2nd argument: `throw :doge, "wow"` This would destroy the whole point of throwing a custom `Object` in my opinion..

Furthermore, what's confusing is that the (first) argument to `throw` used to be restricted to `Symbols` before `ruby 1.9`. Wouldn't this mean that there was somebody that had to `throw` non-Symbols, and ruby had to change their implementation to allow such use cases? Or was it something else.. like saving execution time for a type check.

At this point, the only thing I can imagine throwing apart from `Symbol`s are `Fixnum`s, but was that the reason for the change? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you are using some library whose internals you are not concerned about. What if that library uses a `throw` method with a certain symbol (or any other common object) that accidentally happens to be the same symbol (or an object) that you are `throw`-ing in your own code? It will cause unwanted interactions. On the other hand, if you create a custom object and throw it, you don't have to care about such problems. Especially if you define it only as a local variable, it would be safe. If you define it as a constant, then it would be relatively safe (the danger being that the other library accidentally uses the same constant name in the same name space).

`catch` with a block parameter creates an instance of `Object`, and assign that as a block variable, which makes it safe.

When I use `throw`, I usually cannot use the block variable-form because most of the time, I `throw` and `catch` in different methods. So, I create an instance of `Object`, and assign it as a private constant, which makes it relatively safe.

```
class SomeClass
  Foo = Object.new
  private_constant :Foo

  def some_method
    ...
    catch(Foo){... another_method ...}
    ...
  end
  def another_method
    ...
    throw(Foo)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a misuse of `throw`? From my understanding, `throw` is a way to write a "controlled `goto`", for instance for jumping out from an inner loop. Would it be sane to jump to a place "outside" your application? If I wanted to do this, I would use an exception (`fail`), not `throw`.

Comment: @user1934428 What if it is not an error, but you just want to quit the execution (under a complicated condition), and return to the original position? Using exception is a misuse.

Comment: That's actually a very good explanation. Thank you. Wonder if a similar conversation was held among the Ruby committers too

Comment: @sawa: The original position **outside** my application? Sorry, but I would consider this pretty bad programming style. Note also that an exception doesn't necessarily mean an error in the strict sense (one man's error could be another man's anticipated behaviour), but an "exceptional situation". Think about a library function reading past end-of-file and raising an exception. As a user of this function, I can use it in a good way to catch it and know that I'm done.